# Ajax in function based view

Tags: django, django-forms

I've come a cross a lot of tutorials regarding how to setup a class based view for ajax. Example:

```
class JoinFormView(FormView):
    form_class = JoinForm
    template_name  = 'forms/ajax.html'
    success_url = '/form-success/'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        response = super(JoinFormView, self).form_valid(form)
        if self.request.is_ajax():
            print(form.cleaned_data)
            data = {
                'message': "Successfully submitted form data."
            }
            return JsonResponse(data)
        else:
            return response
```

I'm wondering how would insert the required code for ajax into this function based view. Does the code required depend on whether or not I want to pull from or write to the db asynchronously?

```
def my_func_view(request):
    template = 'accounts/profile.html'
    form = Form123(request.POST or None)    

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save(commit=True)
            return redirect('/accounts/profile/')

        else:
            messages.error(request, 'There was an error.')
            context = {'form': form,}
            return render(request, template, context)

    else:
        context = {'form': form,}

    return render(request, template, context)
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Its not quite clear your problem, sorry, could you clarify?

Comment: How do I build a FBV that supports Ajax requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you do the same thing for the function based view too..

```
from django.http import JsonResponse

def my_func_view(request):
    template = 'accounts/profile.html'
    form = Form123(request.POST or None)    

    if request.is_ajax():
        if form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save(commit=True)
            return JsonResponse({'status':'data'})

        else:
            messages.error(request, 'There was an error.')
            return JsonResponse({'status':'data'})

    else:
        context = {'form': form,}

    return render(request, template, context)
```

Comment: check the request. i guess you have no idea of coding, thus you cant see the changes even. LOL

Comment: Your answer makes no reference to jsonresponse. Does this not need to be in there somewhere?

Comment: you are getting it wrong, it can be anything, either a Jsonresponse or something else, will edit the ans

Comment: Ok. Thanks for putting up with me :) I really appreciate your patience.

Comment: What would the source of 'data' be? Would that be pulled from a form field? Also thanks for the updated answer!

Comment: i have given just a key value pair, you can put anything you want to send back to the frontend ajax success

Comment: Excellent. Thanks so much for your expertise. Answer accepted